# Zabbix agent installation

Tags: macos, monitoring

On the Zabbix website it says Mac OS X agent is supported, however, I do not see a download link available. Does anyone know how to install the agent on OS X?

Here is a link to the list of supported platforms: http://www.zabbix.com/requirements.php

And here's the link to the downloads: http://www.zabbix.com/download.php

There's no OS X option to download for pre-compiled agents.

Answer (score 2):

I was disappointed too.
According to zabbix, it isn't in their plan to distribute a binary agent for Mac. That's a shame.
However, I found a post which describes how to do it yourself. Once compiled (once), you can deploy the agent executable to many machines...
I yet have to try.
http://bluepilltech.blogspot.lu/2015/02/how-to-compile-zabbix-agent-on-osx.html

Answer (score 1):

Use these:
https://github.com/mipmip/zabbix_agentd_osx_installer/releases

They are already compiled and they created a nice installer

Answer (score 1):

These days Zabbix does offer macOS agents for download:
https://www.zabbix.com/download_agents?os=macOS

Answer (score 0):

Install Homebrew.
(You should use this on MacOS for software installation anyways)

https://brew.sh/index_de.html

After installation do:

```
brew install zabbix --without-server-proxy
```

..for a agent only installation or do:

```
brew install zabbix
```

..for a full installation including server and proxy

Comment: Error: invalid option: --without-server-proxy >> getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Installing zabbix via `brew` no longer works:

```
# brew install --without-server-proxy zabbix                                                                                                                                     
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all build scripts full access to your system.
```

Comment: Indeed. I always run Homebrew in a macOS VM if necessary.